# Retrieve many-to-many set and property via HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I have a classes like this:

```
class EntryDB {
     @Id @GeneratedValue
     int id;
     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     List<Category> cats;
}


class Category {
     @Id @GeneratedValue
     int id;
     String name;
}
```

So each entry can be in Zero or more categories. It works fine. But i need to retrive a list of Entries in format entry_id->(cat_id, cat_id, cat_id)

I am trying

```
select id, cats from EntryDB
```

but it does not work and i see Exception like:

DEBUG OUTPUT: Hibernate: select entrydb0_.id as col_0_0_, {non-qualified-property-ref} as col_1_0_, category2_.id as id1_, category2_.name as name1_ from my_entry_table entrydb0_ inner join entrydb_category categories1_ on entrydb0_.id=categories1_.id inner join category category2_ on categories1_.id=category2_.id

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serve...near 'as col_1_0_, category2_.id as id1_, category2_.name as name1_ from my_entry_table' at line 1
```

But HQL like

```
"select cats from EntryDB"
```

works fine. But i need to know id's of Entries.

Just to use

```
session.load(EntryDB.class, id).getCats();
```

is not an option, because the "real" EntryDB is VERY heavy and i just want to know "wich entries are in wich category". It would be very simple, if i could direct access join table, but it's can not be done in HQL.

May be you know some walkaround, but using JDBC to query a join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select entry.id, category.id from EntryDB entry 
left join entry.cats category
```

Comment: By reading the documentation. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql